# Count number of rows with certain columns equal to specific value

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line

I want to counts number of rows with certain columns equal to specific value. Below is a section of the input file:

[image]

The first row is the header. I want to count the number of rows that column 1 equal to 2002, column 3 equal to Female, column 4 equal to 18--20, column 8 equal to CO.

I tried the below command:

```
awk  -F "," '$1=="2002" && $3="Female"&& $4="18--20" && $8 ="CO"{count++};END{print count;}' newData.csv
```

But it didn't work.

I updated the command to above but it still not working. The number it print out is 1116 which is incorrect. This is just the number that column 1 equal to 2002. I need to count the rows that satisfy all the conditions.

Comment: Please don't post data as image, rather copy paste and format it as code {}

Comment: Please don't update your original command after someone posted an answer that makes the answer look stupid. That is not nice. Please add the update in your answer below as additional text.

Comment: And also regard the second sentence of the answer ... `=` does not equal `==` in `awk`.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 2):

`awk` columns are 1-indexed.
`$0` is the full line.

Also, you used `=` instead of `==` several times.

You need:

```
awk  -F "," '$1==2002 && $3=="Female" && $4=="18--20" && $8=="CO"{count++};END{print count;}' newData.csv
```